# Firebase + Angular best way to clear data

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

(Using Angular 4.2.x and angularfire2 4.x)

I currently have the following structure, which allows me to dynamically display each user's data as it changes:

```
// Firebase DB
{
  "users" : {
    "-KtPA3f-UjTPveqMW-aP" : {
      "name" : "person 1",
      "data" : "abc"
    },
    "-KtPA6Ovj_y9Gw_cCxRo" : {
      "name" : "person 2",
      "data" : "def"
    }
  }
}

// component.ts
private getUsers(): FirebaseListObservable<any> {
  return this.db.getUserList();
}

// component.html template
<tr *ngFor="let user of getUsers() | async">
  <td>
    {{user.name}}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{user.data}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

I'd like to be able to quickly clear all users' "data" property.

I was initially thinking of restructuring my DB like this:

```
// Firebase DB
{
  "group": {
    "users": {
      "-KtP9Zo9du3pK3NoBMv7": {
        "name": "person 1"
      },
      "-KtP9Zsz_58v7w4YJOaB": {
        "name": "person 2"
      }
    },
    "userData": {
      "-KtP9Zo9du3pK3NoBMv7": {
        "data": "abc"
      },
      "-KtP9Zsz_58v7w4YJOaB": {
        "data": "def"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

... and then just deleting the "userData" object when necessary, but then I'm not sure how to make use of this structure in my component.ts and my template. I guess I'd somehow need to "join" the objects, but still keep the data dynamic? (I'm new to Angular)

I could also try to write something using the old structure to go through the "users" object and clear each "data" property, but I'm not quite sure how to do that either as I'm also still new to AngularFire.

Any clues welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

what I understood from your question is that you want to delete Users->data properly in all users node is that what you want? 
 I don't know about typescript but I can do this in firebase like, like below

first create object like this

```
var delUserData={};
```

then get all user's list in an array, so that you can loop through it,

```
for (var i=0;i<usersArray.length; i++){
  delUserData["users/"+usersArray[i].$id+"/"+"data"]=null;
});
```

and then pass the delete obj into the firebase query  like

```
 firebase.database().ref().update(delUserData).then(function(){
   alert("Success")
});
```

I have added jsfiddle example [See this example](https://jsfiddle.net/8cf028dx/)